Integrate intl-tel-input React component with React Hook Form Controller wrapper
It's possible to integrate the intl-tel-input React Component (https://intl-tel-input.com/examples/react-component.html) with React Hook Form Controller (https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usecontroller/controller) so when there is an error submitting the form it focus on the telephone form field using TypeScript?
I have tried passing the React Hook Form Controller ref to the IntlTelInput component:
// Parent component
<Controller
    control={control}
    name="phoneE164"
    render={({ field: { ref } }) => (
        <PhoneInput
          inputRef={ref}
          ...
        />
    )}
/>

// Child component
<IntlTelInput
  ref={inputRef)
  ...
/>

But it fails with a "TypeError: elm.focus is not a function".
I also tried passing the ref on the inputProps attributes like this:
// Child component
<IntlTelInput
  inputProps={{
    ref: inputRef,
    ...
  })
/>

And the focus works ok, but breaks the IntlTelInput UI (disapear flags and all the UI elements).
Thanks!

are you using forwardref?

I've tried with forwardref and it didn't work :(

Could you provide a complete example of the problem that can be copied and run?
